# Python "No such file or directory" error

Tags: python

Today I changed my system settings to include C:\python27 as a path variable. Now I am getting the error "IOERROR: [Errno 2} No such file or directory: 'Skusnew1.cvs'" when I run this code:

```
import csv,os,datetime

import dataextract as tde

try:

    tdefile = tde.Extract('SKUS.tde')

except:

    os.remove('SKUS.tde')

    tdefile = tde.Extract('SKUS.tde')


csvReader = csv.reader(open('SKUSnew1.cvs','rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
```

It doesn't like the csvReader line. I have seen on this webpage using something like this:

```
with open('SKUSnew1.cvs', 'rb') as csvReader:
```

but that isn't working either. Does this have to do with changing my path variable or is this just a coincidence? How can it be fixed?

Comment: what you mean did you change the python installation path?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open `Skusnew1.cvs` as a csv file. Typically a csv file has an extension of `csv`. Check to make sure your file has the correct extension.